# Apache Spark: Join two RDDs with different partitioners

Tags: join, apache-spark, partitioning, shuffle, rdd

I have 2 rdds with different set of partitioners.

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, school: String)
case class School(name: String, address: String)
```

`rdd1` is the RDD of `Person`, which I have partitioned based on `age` of the person, and then converted the key to `school`.

```scala
val rdd1: RDD[Person] = rdd1.keyBy(person => (person.age, person))
                            .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))
                            .mapPartitions(persons => 
                                 persons.map{case(age,person) => 
                                    (person.school, person)
                            })
```

`rdd2` is the RDD of `School` grouped by `name` of the school.

```scala
val rdd2: RDD[School] = rdd2.groupBy(_.name)
```

Now, `rdd1` is partitioned based on age of the person, so all persons with same age goes to same partitions. And, `rdd2` is partitioned(by default) based on the name of the school.

I want to `rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2)` in such a way that `rdd1` doesn't get shuffled because rdd1 is very very big compared to rdd2. Also, I'm outputting the result to Cassandra which is partitioned on `age`, so current partitioning of `rdd1` will fasten the process of writing later.

Is there a way to join there two RDDs without:
1. Shuffling `rdd1` and 
2. Broadcasting 'rdd2', because `rdd2` is bigger than the available memory.

Note: The joined rdd should be partitioned based on age.

Comment: Maybe using the signature `leftOuterJoin[W](other: RDD[(K, W)], partitioner: Partitioner)`, and using the same partitioner as rdd1 may help.

Comment: Both are `HashPartitioner` on different keys. How do we specify a custom key in `HashPartitioner`? It accepts only number of partitions as input.

Comment: Note: Size of rdd1 ~100GB, and size of rdd2 ~ 10GB. 

I have 15 such rdd2's which have to be joined with `rdd1`. And, each such smaller rdd's (rdd2 here) gets joined with different keys in rdd1. To avoid shuffle of rdd1 I have partitioned it based on a fixed key so that it doesn't get shuffled.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I cannot think of an easy way to do it with HashPartitioner, have you considered creating your own Partitioner? It's not as hard as it seems.

Comment: Hi @DanielPaula, yes I have considered using a custom partitioner. But the glitch there is, I see in the api it has to be defined on the key of the RDD. I want to customPartition my RDD based on some other data, which is not the key.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two rdds, rdd1 and rdd2 and want to apply join operation. and if rdds has partitioned (partition is set). then calling rdd3 = rdd1.join(rdd2) will make rdd3 partition by rdd1. rdd3 will always take hash partition from rdd1 (first parent, the one that join was called on).