# Spark: How can we remove partitioner from RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioner

I am grouping a RDD based on a key.

```
rdd.groupBy(_.key).partitioner
=> org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner@a
```

I see that by default Spark, associates `HashPartitioner` with this RDD, which is fine by me because I agree that we need some kind of partitioner to bring alike data to one executor. But, later in the program I want the RDD to forget about its partitioner strategy because I want to join it with another RDD which follows different partitioning strategy. How can we remove the partitioner from the RDD?

Comment: a simple map operation will do the job.
I don't think it required, when you are going to perform join action on pairedRDD, you can specify partitioner which will partition the RDD again.

Comment: Thank you @shekhar, I wrote rdd.map(e => e) and it worked.
Actually the real problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051718/apache-spark-join-two-rdds-with-different-partitioners . I thought I make it work by making one of the rdd forget about its partitioner. Do you happen to know another way around?

Comment: can't you broadcast 2nd RDD and then apply in memory join by iterating over 1st RDD??

Comment: No, even 2nd RDD is too big(~10GB) for broadcating, and I have 15 other such RDDs which have to be joined with rdd1 which is ~100GB